# Impala query lead to error message that parquet has an invalid file length: 0

Tags: hadoop, parquet, impala

In my project, hadoop is used and files are created in hdfs with parquet format. Data is partitioned by date in hdfs.
Data for current date is created and store for current date always in new files.

The issue is that sql query issue from from HUE web console (Impala) failing always complaining some file hdfs file from current date has an invalid file length:0.

Any idea how to improve situation here, so any query which is issued from HUE web UI for Impala always provide result instead of invalid file length: 0 error?